# Memory error. Process on GPU uses CPU/system memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

[image]

After updating the tensorflow image to **22.01-tf2-py3**, models that used to train, now give me a memory error. Tensorflow seem to be using system memory not GPU, and the program stops after initializacing.

After doing some research, I have found that the problem is the **CPU/system memory** allocated for this process when I'm running on **GPU**. Also, tf process on GPU uses much more memory than dataset size.

From what I had read, tensorflow copy output tensor from GPU memory to CPU. What do I not understand it is why this problem appear after update image? And how can I fix it?

#EDIT: My grid search loop had too many parameters, when I reduce it to a single model, it does train, does it make sense? does it load all models a priori when I enter the loop?

#EDIT2: If I use the tensorflow image **21.03-tf2-py3** it does let me train and everything goes fine, why does this happen, is it due to some tensorflow update?

Comment: Please never add error messages as images, it is barely readable and not searchable. And please read https://xyproblem.info/, you seem to be asking us about what you think the solution is, and not about what the problem itself. You seem to be trying to allocate 52GB of GPU RAM which no GPU can do.

Answer (score 0):

That's not your dataset the problem. The fitting part isn't started. The Timedistributed layer is the problem.
The application of a dense layer is repeated for each output of the previous layer. 105 * definition of the dense layer passed to the Timedistributed layer * connections to each variable.
The result : 52 go of weights and associated variables...

Comment: But, I used to train models with TimeDistributed...

Comment: If I load few videos, I can train. Model:
    inp = layers.Input(shape=(105, 224, 224, 3))
    base_model = ResNet50V2(include_top=False,
                                pooling='max',
                                weights='imagenet',
                                input_shape=dim,
                                )
    x = layers.TimeDistributed(base_model)(inp)
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(units=units))(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = layers.Dense(64)(x)
    out = layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inp, out)

Comment: So use a very low batch_size, your model is very big.